# Jython ImportError: No module named * (only on Windows Server 2012)

Tags: python, jython, windows-server-2012

I have a CreateDomain.py script for weblogic. And now I want to import a java class in the python script. I exported the class com.swisslog.python.util.FileNameUtil to a jar and added it to the class path before calling the python script.

Here's the start of the script:

```
from wlstModule import *
from java.io import FileInputStream
from java.util import Properties
import jarray.array
import os
import shutil
import traceback
import sys
import getopt
from com.swisslog.python.util import FileNameUtil
```

I start the script from a bat file:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;wm6-python-util.jar
%MW_HOME%\wlserver\common\bin\wlst.cmd common\CreateDomain.py %1 %2 %3 %4
```

This works on Windows 7. But on Windows Server 2012 I get following error:

```
ImportError: no module named swisslog
```

Also using the full path doesn't work ([jython ImportError: No module named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754402/jython-importerror-no-module-named))

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's in `sys.modules['com']` when you do only `import com`? Does that match the package path that `com.swisslog` is in?

Comment: it prints `<java package com 1>` for both `import com` and `from com import *`

Answer (score 1):

I found a stupid workaround. I added a main method which calls the real methods and prints the result with system.out.print. Then I can start the jar from the python script without an import:

```
    result = os.popen(['java', '-jar', 'python-util.jar', 'arg').read()
```